# What is the default response code of the php header function

Tags: php

When I redirect users using the `header()` function, only passing the first argument, what response code will be send?

I had `header('Location: https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);` set for some time on old pages, and now I'm curious if that redirect might have been cached by browsers.

Comment: `200` is the default `OK` response.

Comment: When you redirect them how? Using `Location: ...` ?

Comment: if you use header("Location" you should get a 302. You can read this in the docs already. Or you could have tested it about as quickly as writing a question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will send a 302 (temporary redirect) if you send a `Location` header and don't specify otherwise. [From the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

> The second special case is the "Location:" header. Not only does it send this header back to the browser, but it also returns a REDIRECT (302) status code to the browser unless the 201 or a 3xx status code has already been set.

**Edit:**
So, to answer your follow-up query: no, this should not have been cached.

Answer (score 0):

- `200` when the page loads
- `404` when the page cannot be found
- `500` when the page returnes an error
- etc...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Answer (score 0):

There are two special-case header calls. The first is a header that starts with the string "HTTP/" (case is not significant), which will be used to figure out the HTTP status code to send. For example, if you have configured Apache to use a PHP script to handle requests for missing files (using the ErrorDocument directive), you may want to make sure that your script generates the proper status code.

for more details , please check `http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php`